# Show form in specific pages in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form and I put that in a blade template and I want to show it in some of my category pages and not all of them. So I created a table which gets categories ID's and another column as `n` or `y` to let me say show that form in category with this id or not.

### Issue

The issue is that no matter what I choose `n` or `y` my form loads in all of my categories pages.

### Codes

`Category model`

```
public function categoryfinderactivess(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(CategoryFinderActive::class, 'category_finder_actives', 'category_id', 'active');
  }
```

`CategoryFinderActive model`

```
class CategoryFinderActive extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
      'category_id', 'active',
    ];

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');


}
```

}

`controller`

```
$finderactive = CategoryFinderActive::where('category_id', $category->id)->where('active', '=', 'y')->get();
```

`blade`

```
@if($finderactive)
  @include('front.partials.indexPage.catfinder')
@endif
```

`screenshot`

[image: screenone]

Any idea?

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?

Comment: In your controller you can do `dd($finderactive);` to check if you're getting any data or not.

Comment: try `@if($finderactive && count($finderactive))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use @includeWhen directive of [blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#including-sub-views).

Something like this:

```
@includeWhen( ($finderactive && (count($finderactive) > 0) ), 'front.partials.indexPage.catfinder')
```

Good luck!!!

Comment: thanks for the answer, it seems to be working however i need double check it in different conditions. what i don't get is what `count` using for here?

Comment: count function will check that your $finderactive variable contains any value value?